# Is it possible to change the compiler in ROS?

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am the beginner for ROS and trying to run the AspectC++, but now I am stuck with the compilation issue. Since the AspectC++ is using ac++ or ag++, while the ROS is using c++ compiler, I am wondering if we can change the compiler of ROS to some other else? And how? Please help and Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32032/is-it-possible-to-change-the-compiler-in-ros?/) by [supat](https://answers.ros.org/users/2196/supat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CMake honors the CC and CXX environment variable so you can use whatever compiler you prefer by setting these variables. For instance, I use ccache for all my ROS compilation without any trouble.

```
 export CC=/path/to/my/c/compiler
 export CXX=/path/to/my/c++/compiler
 rosmake
```

You can then double check which compiler has been used by running:

```
grep COMPILER CMakeCache.txt
```

...in any ROS build directory. CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER should be your custom C++ compiler.

Unless you recompile ROS from scratch, you *will* have to make sure that the ABI are compatible (i.e. that you can link a g++ library against an aspectc++ one).

Be aware that porting the code so that it is compatible with a new compiler is *a lot of work*. Do not do it unless you are already a C++ experienced programmer and ready to spend a couple of months on this.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-26**:
I've tried this for building catkin libraries (on OS X), but no luck -- it still just uses clang.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Didn't you already ask this question??? Why can't you just compile ROS with g++ and write your nodes with AspectC++? If AspectC++ doesn't support this, then it would probably take a lot of work to fix ROS.

I have never heard of AspectC++ before, so I could be wrong. Please take a look at the [REPs](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0000.html) to help understand what ROS is ... specifically [REP-3 Target Platforms](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) and [REP-9 ABI Compatibility](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0009.html) to see if AspectC++ violates those. Some of the other ones might be useful to read too.
Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1